# Old versions of Castle Project

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, castle-activerecord, castle

This might be a stupid questions - but Castle Project (castleproject.org) does not seem to give access to all previous versions of their projects, only the latest releases.

Does anyone know where I can get older releases? Specifically for ActiveRecord and Windsor. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [All Windsor releases](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/Windsor/)
- [All ActiveRecord releases](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/ActiveRecord/)
- [All releases of the Castle project from when it was all a single release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/Castle%20Project/) (RC3 and before).